# getting atrr each selector after clicked on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why don't work this js code? after click:
output `form #find_sc` is "true". 
output `.pagination a` is "undefined" . 
"there is no" output in `form select option` (In this case the alert is not displayed).

```
$('.pagination a, form #find_sc, form select option').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.pagination a')){
    var dirc = $(this).attr('href'); // this is a link tag <a></a>
    }
    if($('form #find_sc')){
    var dirc = $(this).attr('class'); // this is a button tag <button></button>
    }
    if($('form select option')){
    var dirc = $(this).attr('class'); // this is a selectbox. i want after click on option in it, was active and attr class in selectbox. <select><option></option></select>
    }
    alert(dirc);
        $.get( dirc, function(html) {            
            //$('#ok').append(html);
            $('#num_count').replaceWith( $(html).find('#num_count') );
            $('tr#paginate').replaceWith( $(html).find('tr#paginate') );
            $('.pagination').replaceWith( $(html).find('.pagination') );           
            });
        return false;
    });
```

What is your solutions or suggestions?

**EDIT:** please click on following images in my example

`form #find_sc` --is this--> [image]
`.pagination a` --is this--> [image]
`form select option` --is this--> [image]

-> [i want after click on option in select, was active and attr class in selectbox.]
**EXAMPLE:** [my problem in here](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show)

Answer (score 1):

You can't know which of the jQuery selectors "triggered" the event.

You know only the active element, which is `$(this)` so just take either its `href` attribute, if exists, or otherwise take its `class` attribute:

```
$('.pagination a, form #find_sc, form select option').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sender = $(this);
    var dirc = sender.attr("href") || sender.attr("class");
    alert(dirc);
    ...
});
```

Edit: to catch drop down list change event, you can't use the `click` instead of `change`. To prevent duplicating your code, put it into a named function:

```
function MyEventHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sender = $(this);
    var dirc = sender.attr("href") || sender.attr("class");
    alert(dirc);
    ...
}
```

Then attach the proper events:

```
$('form select').live('change', MyEventHandler);
$('.pagination a, form #find_sc').live('click', MyEventHandler);
```

Comment: ok, tanks, but not work for attr in class to select. `sender.closest('select').attr('class')` html-> `<select class="ok"><option>5</option></select>` and selctor in js is -> `$('form select option')`???

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I saw are the conditions given inside the `if` statements

For example, `$('.pagination a')` will always be true even if it points to no elements. This is a JQuery object due to which it is a truthy value.
Similarly for other `if` conditions.

Replace the if conditions with the check for `length` property. That is, replace `$('.pagination a')` with `$('.pagination a').length`

`length` returns the number of elements pointed by this variable

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `length` property to check whether `jQuery` returned any elements or not. Also in the `get` success handler you can cache `$(html)` into a local variable and use it at multiple places. Try this

```
$('.pagination a, form #find_sc, form select option').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.pagination a').length > 0){
    var dirc = $(this).attr('href'); // this is a link tag <a></a>
    }
    if($('form #find_sc').length > 0){
    var dirc = $(this).attr('class'); // this is a button tag <button></button>
    }
    if($('form select option').length > 0){
    var dirc = $(this).attr('class'); // this is a selectbox. i want after click on option in it, was active and attr class in selectbox. <select><option></option></select>
    }
    alert(dirc);
        $.get( dirc, function(html) {            
            var $html = $(html);
            $('#num_count').replaceWith( $html.find('#num_count') );
            $('tr#paginate').replaceWith( $html.find('tr#paginate') );
            $('.pagination').replaceWith( $html.find('.pagination') );           
            });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you alert `$('form select option').length` and see what you get?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i want getting value attr in js code (after each click on selector it). but in selectbox i want after click on option in select, was active and attr class in select. how is it?